# What is different about contactless terminals on public transit?

Tags: contactless

I have a credit card issued by a small financial institution. The credit card is equipped with contactless payment technology, which works at all brick-and-mortar retailers. However, the contactless feature does not seem to work at all on public transit systems. I have tried to use this card to pay for the New York City Subway (OMNY readers), London Underground, and on various buses equipped with contactless payment options in the UK and Ireland. On these readers the card *never* works. On buses that are capable of printing a receipt, it says that the card was declined.

I have contacted the financial institution, and they say they cannot see the declined transaction and so are unable to diagnose the problem. What I am wondering is whether there is some known difference between the contactless readers on public transit systems and the contactless payment systems used by other merchants, e.g. a different procedure for processing the transaction or something like that, that could be disabled or not available on certain contactless cards. Then I could write to the institution and suggest that that may be the issue with the card they have issued.

Comment: What type of card? Visa, Mastercard....?

Comment: It is a Visa card

Comment: It might be because of the issuing bank. These systems can block at the BIN (also known as IIN) level - the first six digits of the long number. These identify the issuing institution.

Comment: I wonder is there a potential flag for attended and unattended terminals and your card doesn't allow you to pay if there is no vendor present.  Perhaps someone here can say whether that is a feature that cards can have.  You might try using your card in a vending machine or some other unattended location to check if it works there.

Comment: @AakashM that is possible but it would be a bit surprising given that it doesn't work on such a variety of public transit operators.

Comment: @EricNolan that is the kind of thing I am wondering about. It does work in vending machines.

Comment: My thought was - how do these transit systems work? Do you pay up-front or after you finish riding? Maybe there is a special system to let the transit company charge you only after you finish riding based on how far you rode.

Comment: @user253751 they vary: some you just tap the card to enter while some you tap to both enter and exit

Comment: When I used my Visa Debit card on the London Underground about eight years ago, I seem to remember having to register the card on the TfL (Transport for London) website before it could be used for contactless payments. No idea if that's still the case.

Comment: Are you sure the contactless terminal is meant for credit cards and not a prepaid card issued by the transit authority? The Washington DC metro system has contactless terminals, but they only work with physical prepaid cards issued by WMATA (SmarTrip Card), or your personal phone if you load the prepaid card onto Apple Pay or Google Pay.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus, yes and indeed I have another credit card that works on these terminals, with no need to register it

Answer (score 2):

It's possible your card issuer doesn't permit this type of use, and maybe you should ask them.  For example, many cards issued by sub-prime banks do not allow card holders to pay for gas at the pump, and instead they're required to go inside to pay.  I don't know the purpose behind this rule, but it must make sense to somebody.  Clearly though, the banks have the ability to restrict which networks and types of transactions their cards can be used for.

In any case, not every card will work everywhere - it depends on whether the bank participates in the network the merchant is using, the rules the bank has established for use of its cards and so on.  Best answer there is to call/email your bank and ask.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I have contacted the bank, and they are unaware of any such restriction. That is why I am asking what might be special about this type of transaction, or even what such transactions are called, so that I could ask them more specifically what the problem might be.

Comment: If it isn't the bank, then it has to be the merchant processor for the transit systems that perhaps doesn't accept your bank's card.  That's the only remaining explanation.  That can happen because the transaction fees are higher than they're willing to pay or any number of other reasons.  Believe it or not, depending on your bank AND the program your card is a part of (such as cash back rewards and so on), it changes the bank interchange fees for processed transactions.  At last glance, there were more than 4,000 separate interchange fees across all issued credit cards.  It's crazy.